# Laravel activity log does not update properties column on laravel 9

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I always use the package spatie/laravel-activitylog, but when i upgrade laravel at the new versions, i find in the table activity log some rows with properties [].

This is my model

```
protected static $logAttributes = [
        'date',
        'state',
        'old_state',
    ];


public function getActivitylogOptions(): LogOptions
    {
        return LogOptions::defaults();
    }
```

How i can fix this problem?

I always use the package spatie/laravel-activitylog, but when i upgrade laravel at the new versions, i find in the table activity log some rows with properties [].
How i can fix this problem?

Comment: Welcome to SO, please consider this posting about [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.